# How to compare 2 field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Ok, I have example result on my data in elastic search :

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "solutionpedia_data",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "nyODP24BA840z5O6WguE",
        "_score" : 46.63439,
        "_source" : {
          "ID" : "1",
          "PRODUCT_NAME" : "ATM",
          "UPDATEDATE" : "13-FEB-18",
          "PROPOSAL" : [
            {
            }
          ],
          "MARKETING_KIT" : [ ],
          "VIDEO" : [ ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "classification",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "5M-r5m4BNYha4zuWalJa",
        "_score" : 39.25268,
        "_source" : {
          "productId" : "1",
          "productName" : "ATM",
          "productIconUrl" : "media/8ae0f0c3-1402-4559-901e-7ec9b874ce68-prod032.webp",
          "type" : "nonconnectivity",
          "businessLineId" : "",
          "subsidiaries" : "",
          "segment" : [],
          "productType" : "Efisien",
           "tariff" : null,
          "tags" : [ ],
          "contact" : [],
          "mediaId" : [
            "Med391"
          ],
          "documentId" : [
            "doc260",
            "doc261"
          ],
          "createdAt" : "2019-09-22T05:22:46.956Z",
          "updatedAt" : "2019-09-22T05:22:46.956Z",
          "totalClick" : 46
        }
      }
    ]
```

this is a result of my alias. can we search for the same data based on 2 different fields, the example above is the ID and productId fields. Can we make these 2 objects in one bucket or compare?

i was try with some aggregate but nothing :

```
{
  "query": {
       "match_all": {}
    },
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "product catalog": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "productId.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 2,
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "product solped": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ID.keyword",
            "min_doc_count": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

result :

```
{
  "took" : 9,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 10,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1276,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "product catalog" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the query too.

Comment: done brother @Shubh

Comment: So basically you are looking to aggregate on two fields ??

Comment: Yeah i want to join 2 object went value of id and productId has a same value

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a [Scripted Bucket Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html), using script logic to define your buckets (pseudo code: if field a exists value of field a, if field b exists value of field b).

Another (and better) way to achieve this is to change your data model and indexing logic on Elasticsearch side and store the information in a field of the same name.

You could also consider the [alias data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/alias.html) to make fields with different names in different indices accessible under one common field name. This is also the approach Elastic takes with the [Elastic Common Schema](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/index.html) specification.